# Trim string returned from Get-Package query

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I would like to request some help with extracting out some characters that are returned from a Powershell query.

The query is:

`$x = Get-Package -Provider "Programs" -Name "*SomeWindowsApplication*" | Select-Object -Property FastPackageReference | Out-String`

The returned format is

```
FastPackageReference
---------------------
hklm32\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{80F3CCC1-BBAF-45DD}
```

I am trying to extract (to a variable) just the value returned within the { } *curly brackets*

When using
`$x.TrimStart("hklm32")`
or
`$x.Trim("hklm32")`
neither appear to make any change to the string.

I've tested that it is a string using `$x.GetType()`

The outcome I require is a variable eg: *$appvalue* which when queried returns the value eg: *{80F3CCC1-BBAF-45DD}* including the { } brackets.

Thanks, much appreciated for any assistance.

update: a colleague of mine suggested this code, which works but it assumes the GUID is always 38 characters. (might not be a problem for this application though)

`$GUID=$x.substring($x.IndexOf("{"),38)`

[Regex101.com - Result using REGEX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HotGL.png)

Comment: You could use a regex on that result. For example: `$x -match '{.*}'`, then you need to check the [`$Matches`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.2#groups-captures-and-substitutions) variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me complement [Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71204125/45375), which shows advanced [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) techniques, with simpler alternatives, if the following assumption can be made:

Given that it looks like the substring of interest is the last `\`-separated token, an alternative to using a regex is to treat the string as a *path* and extract its *leaf* (file-name) component via [`Split-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path):

```sh
# Get the property value(s) of interest.
$x = (Get-Package -Provider Programs -Name *SomeWindowsApplication*).FastPackageReference

# -> '{80F3CCC1-BBAF-45DD}', with your sample data
Split-Path -Leaf $x
```

A more concise regex-solution is possible too, using a [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operation:

```sh
$x -replace '^[^{]+'
```

The regex matches from the start of the input string (`^`) one or more characters (`+`) that are *not* `{` (`[^{]`), i.e. everything up to but not including `{`; by not specifying a replacement string, the matched part is replaced with the empty string i.e. effectively *removed*, leaving only the `{...}` part at the end.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to remove  `| Out-String`, because what you are after is the **value** inside property `FastPackageReference`

Try:

```
$x = Get-Package -Provider "Programs" -Name "*SomeWindowsApplication*" | Select-Object -Property FastPackageReference
$guid = ([regex]'(?i){([\dA-F-]+)}$').Match($x.FastPackageReference).Groups[1].Value
```

or

```
# expand the property, so $x will only have the value, not an object with property FastPackageReference
$x = Get-Package -Provider "Programs" -Name "*SomeWindowsApplication*" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FastPackageReference
$guid = ([regex]'(?i){([\dA-F-]+)}$').Match($x).Groups[1].Value
```

Variable `$guid` now has value `80F3CCC1-BBAF-45DD`

Regex details:

```
{               Match the character “{” literally
(               Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   [\dA-F-]     Match a single character present in the list below
                A single digit 0..9
                A character in the range between “A” and “F”
                The character “-”
      +         Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
}               Match the character “}” literally
$               Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character)
```

The `(?i)` makes the regex work case-insensitively

Comment: tested with website regex101 and it matches. However in PS I get the following result 
`echo $AppGUID
hklm32\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{80F3CCC1-BBAF-45DD-B7B6-EF019441F9B5}`

`$guid = ([regex]'(?i){([\dA-F-]+)}$').Match($AppGUID).Groups[1].Value`

`echo $guid`

returns no result.

Comment: @42sth We don't know what your variable `$AppGUID` contains.. Do `$AppGUID.GetType().FullName`. By using `echo` you are forcing PowerShell to **stringify** whatever that var contains so it may just **look** like a string in the console. [1] If it is indeed a string, try `..Match($AppGUID.Trim())..` to make sure it doesn't contain trailing whitespace. [2] If it is an **object** then you may have missed getting the actual **value** from it with `Match($AppGUID.FastPackageReference)` You did remove `Out-String` didn't you??

Comment: Thankyou for the explanation. I see where the problem was (see conversation below with @mklement0. ) The variable `$AppGUID` was indeed not a string. Once this was resolved by removing ` | fl `  all suggested methods worked. 
And thanks for the tip `$AppGUID.GetType().FullName` was useful in verifying the issue.
Yes, I did indeed remove `Out-String`